# Dialogbox over another dialogbox app crashes

Tags: android, radio-button, android-alertdialog

I am trying to create a dialogbox in which there are some edittexts and two radio buttons. But the app crashes forcefully due to java.lang.NullPointerException. Any help with this will be really helpfull. I tried popup menu instead of radio button but still same java.lang.NullPointerException error.

```js
custom_dialog

<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
    
   
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/ET_Name"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:hint="Name"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/ET_Email"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
        android:hint="Email"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/ET_Mobile"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="phone"
        android:hint="Mobile"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/POP_Country"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Select Country"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/ET_City"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:hint="City"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/POP_Pack"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Select Package"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/ET_Info"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
        android:hint="Additional Information"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />

   <RelativeLayout 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp" >
    
    
     <Button
        android:id="@+id/submit"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/view"
        android:text="Submit" />

   
    
     <View
        android:id="@+id/view"
        android:layout_width="3dp"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
     
      <Button
        android:id="@+id/reset"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/submit"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/view"
        android:text="Reset" />   

   

</RelativeLayout>    

</LinearLayout>
    

</ScrollView>
```

```css
activity_main

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/RL"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.dialogwithspinner.MainActivity" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="170dp"
        android:text="Button"
        android:onClick="Function" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

```html
MainActivity

package com.example.dialogwithspinner;


import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.PopupMenu;
import android.widget.PopupWindow;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
 
 String[] countries = { "Cupcake", "Donut", "Eclair", "Froyo",
      "Gingerbread", "HoneyComb", "IceCream Sandwich", "Jellybean",
      "Cote D'ivoire" };
 
 //RelativeLayout rl;

 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
  
  //rl = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.RL);
  
  final Button btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.POP_Country);
  
  
  final AlertDialog.Builder ad = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
  ad.setSingleChoiceItems(countries, -1,  new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

   @Override
   public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    dialog.dismiss();
    Button POP_Country = (Button)findViewById(R.id.POP_Country);
    POP_Country.setText(countries[which]);

   }
   
  });
  
  btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
   
   @Override
   public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    ad.show();
   }
  }); 

  
  
  
 }  //onCreate ends
 
 public void Function(View v){
  final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(MainActivity.this);
  dialog.setContentView(R.layout.custom_dialog);
  dialog.setTitle("Enquiry Form");
  dialog.setCancelable(true);
  
  Button submit = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.submit);
  submit.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
   
   @Override
   public void onClick(View view) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Submitted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
   }
  });
  Button reset = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.reset);
  reset.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
   
   @Override
   public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    EditText ET_Name = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.ET_Name);
    EditText ET_Email = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.ET_Email);
    EditText ET_Mobile = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.ET_Mobile);
    EditText ET_City = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.ET_City);
    EditText ET_Info = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.ET_Info);
    Button POP_Country = (Button)findViewById(R.id.POP_Country);
    Button POP_Pack = (Button)findViewById(R.id.POP_Pack);
    ET_Name.setText("");
    ET_Email.setText("");
    ET_Mobile.setText("");
    ET_City.setText("");
    ET_Info.setText("");
    POP_Country.setText("");
    POP_Pack.setText("");
    
   }
  });
  dialog.show();

 }
 
 /*public void Country_List(View view){
  ad.show();
  
 } */
 

} //Activity ends
```

Comment: Could you please post the exception StackTrace please ?

Comment: logcat always shows the line which leads to crush. read it

Comment: http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=ofdeh1&s=8#.VcB-wfOqqko

Comment: The above is the link for logcat

Comment: Include the logcat output in your question. The screenshot doesn't help. I'm guessing that btn is null.

Comment: @SomnathPal Did you solve yet ?